Is the PowerQuery SSIS source buggy? Same PQ works perfectly in Excel and PowerBI
I have an Excel file that contains a PowerQuery query to parse a PDF, and it works perfectly. It finds and reads the contents of a table in the PDF and basically cleans it up.
I wanted to see if I could have that same code run in SSIS so that I could pass a folder of files there and persist the data scraped from the PDFs in the M code to my SQL Server database. Since I am pretty much a rank beginner at SSIS, I started with a simple Excel file and imported from that and mapped the Excel Source columns to my database table columns, and it worked a champ.
then I used the PowerQuery connector to extract the contents of the PDF in a new dataflow, and pasted in the exact same M code that ran successfully in Excel. But when I went to map the output of the PowerQuery to the destination table in SQL Server, none of the columns in the PowerQuery were visible in the source. It was completely blank. (as if the columns had never been read or evaluated).
Am I doing something wrong, or is this just how the PowerQuery transform works in SSIS?
